# Weighted Averages/uncertainty

Tags: statistics

Two results were obtained from an experiment, $12 \pm 2$ and $9 \pm 3$. Having a weighted average of $(x)=11.08$.
1.find its uncertainty of this results.
2. What are the $90\%$ confidence limits on the weighted mean? (By $x\%$ confidence limits we mean the (usually symmetric) boundaries within which $x\%$ of the area falls.
Hint: $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_a^b \exp(\frac{-z^2}{2}) \textrm{d}z = 0.90$ between the limits of $a=-1.645$ and $b=1.645$.

For part 1: using the formula $$\sigma = \left(\sum_{i=1}^2 \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2} \right)^\frac{-1}{2} = \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} \right)^\frac{-1}{2} = 1.66$$

therefore $(x) = 11.08 \pm 1.66$

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: I am struggling with the last part 90% confidence limits

Comment: Then I would suggest adding your work on  the first part, so that we see what you've done. And there is no unnecessary work done when we give you direction on the first part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used normality here (the CDF that you have used is the Gaussian one). 
Hint: the standard error of the mean is 
$$
SE_{\mu}=\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Consequently, the 90% confidence interval would be: $$CI({\mu})=({\mu}\pm1 645SE_{\mu})$$

where $s$ is the sample standard deviation of the observations.